# better option for string concatenation

Tags: java, optimization

I have a category hierarchy like A->B->C-D with at max 4 levels,In this code I have a leaf category for which I need to get the pipe separated names of category hierarchy from root to leaf like A|B|C|D. I have two approaches which will be best from performance and garbage collection point of view?

Approach#1

```
String names = category.getName();
Category parentCategory = category.getParent();
while(parentCategory.getParent() !=null){
   names = parentcategory.getName() + "|" + names;
   parentCategory = parentCategory.getParent();
}
```

Approach#2

```
Deque<String> stack = new ArrayDeque<>();
stack.push(category.getName());
Category parentCategory = category.getParent();
while(parentCategory.getParent() !=null){
   stack.push(parentCategory.getName())
   parentCategory = parentCategory.getParent();
}
String name = String.join("|", stack);
```

As I understand in approach#1 a lot of temporary string objects will be created but will be fast, In approach#2 there will be an additional loop for joining the strings.

Please suggest me with the best way if there I can apply besides above 2.

Comment: Have you profiled/benchmarked?

Comment: Use a `StringBuilder` to avoid the temporary objects in approach #1. If you can *guess* the expected size reasonably well (or have an upper bound), then that approach will need very few allocations.

Comment: Also, let me point out that while approach #1 creates "a lot" of temporary objects in the general case, it's not actually that bad if you have at most 4 levels. Here you'll create 3 "unnecessary" `String` objects that will quickly be garbage collected. That's not usually a problem at all.

Comment: The same code will be executed at least 25K times for products. I think at that time it will not be good, what do you think?

Comment: @nitin: can't really say by that number. 25k times in what time? In a year? What else is the code doing? If your mostly waiting for an ancient database on a host that has CPU and memory to spare, then it doesn't matter. In the end it all depends on context.

Comment: @JoachimSauer this code is getting executed inside a loop, and there might be 25k iterations.

Answer (score 1):

Using a `StringBuilder` you can easily avoid the temporary `String` objects:

```
String categoryPath(Category category) {
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    // if you know that for example there's at most 4 levels and most categories
    // have a name that's less than 10 characters, then you can use
    // `new StringBuilder(43)` instead (10*4 + 3 separator characters).
    sb.append(category.getName());
    category = category.getParent();
    while (category != null) {
        sb.insert(0, '|');
        sb.insert(0, category.getName());
        category = category.getParent();
    }
    return sb.toString();
}
```

Note that this version uses `sb.insert()` which will require array copies of the whole existing String, so it *might* be sub-optimal (measure it if you want to know for sure). You can use the call stack to avoid that by making a recursive helper function:

```
String categoryPath(Category category()) {
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(MNAX_DEPTH * MAX_NAME_LENGTH + (MAX_DEPTH-1));
    categoryPathImpl(category, sb);
    return sb.toString();
}

private categoryPathImpl(Category category, StringBuilder sb) {
    Category parent = category.getParent();
    if (parent != null) {
        categoryPathImpl(parent, sb);
        sb.append('|');
    }
    sb.append(category);
}
```

Comment: You miss the '0' parameter at the second insert()

Answer (score 0):

In terms of efficence, the best is the approach#1, but using a `StringBuilder` for `name` variable, then call `toString()` on it:

```
StringBuilder name = new StringBuilder();

// this string allocation is useless too, the getter is removed by compiler and a direct access is performed
// String names = category.getName(); 

Category parentCategory = category.getParent();
while(parentCategory.getParent() !=null){
   name.append(parentcategory.getName()
       .append("|")
       .append(category.getName());
   parentCategory = parentCategory.getParent();
}
String nameString = name.toString();
```

In this way you have same behavior, same speed but avoid to create temporary strings.

Anyway, your code don't looks to works as expected, if you are in a leaf "D" and want to have the string "A|B|C|D" you have to add strings names in reverse order, then reverse the whole string at the end.

So your code becomes:

```
Category parentCategory = category;
StringBuilder name = new StringBuilder(category.getName());

while(parentCategory.getParent() !=null){
   parentCategory = parentCategory.getParent();
   StringBuilder parentName = new StringBuilder(parentcategory.getName()).reverse();
   name.append("|").
       .append(parentName);

}


String nameString = name.reverse().toString();
```

Comment: This doesn't work corretly, you'll keep appending `category.getName()` multiple times. Note that `name` is **not** useless, because it gets re-assigned inside the loop.

Comment: @JoachimSauer  This not works in the same way the posted code not works, I don't changed anything, please look better the variables name, the variable `names` is never reassigned

Comment: `names = parentcategory.getName() + "|" + names;` is straight from OPs post.

Comment: I edited bit later the original code line to 
names = parentcategory.getName() + "|" + names;
initially it was wrong, that was my mistake:
name = parentcategory.getName() + "|" + names;

Comment: @nitin I've edited my answer with a solution for your mistake too

Comment: @JoachimSauer just see OPs comment above here!

Comment: `reverse()` only works as expected when each name is at most 1 character, which I suspect is not the case, given that they are category names ... it's probably just the sample data that does this.

Comment: right @JoachimSauer this is sample data, in realtime it will be like Furniture -> Sitting -> Couch

Comment: @nitin i've update answer again according with real data

Answer (score -2):

You can also user StringBuilder in the first approach as it is fast and appends values further. Check if this can help

```
String names = category.getName(); -->  StringBuilder names = new StringBuilder(category.getName());
        Category parentCategory = category.getParent();
        while(parentCategory.getParent() !=null){
           name = parentcategory.getName() + "|" + names;
           parentCategory = parentCategory.getParent();
        }
```

Comment: Just creating StringBuilder for `names` will not going to append for `name` variable.

Comment: It is just a heads up, to appends names append() method need to use.